# Tensorflow RNN API static_rnn

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently learning RNN and Tensorflow RNN APIs.

For `tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn`, it has one argument `initial_state` which is a optional argument. What is the difference between passing in an initial state and without passing an initial state? If I don't add the initial_state, is that mean the RNN internal state output would not be carried forward?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The basic RNN equation is along the lines of `state_t = nonlinearity(matmul(state_t-1, state_weights) + matmul(input_t, input_weights))`. That is, the state at a given time step depends on the state at the previous time step. This is a recursive definition and thus needs a "recursive stop" which is what the initial state is, i.e. `state_0` (or `state_-1` I suppose if you start indexing your inputs at 0...).

If you don't pass an initial state, Tensorflow defaults to using a tensor of zeros. One alternative would be to make it trainable (by using a `tf.Variable`) instead. Another example of handling the initial state would be encoder-decoder architectures, where one network (encoder) computes an output that is then used as the initial state to the decoder.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!